# Installation Error When starting Noodle.js bin

Tags: node.js

Im trying to install Noodle.js on my computer. when I try to start it up, Im getting this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7UhX.jpg

Im new to node, so this is beyond me.

Comment: This first issue was not actually "installing" it
http://imgur.com/RKjaz1g

But then I came across the error: "Cant find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable."

Which I googled and tried but without success...

Comment: System Variable PythonPath: "C:\PYTHON34;C:\PYTHON34\DLLs;C:\PYTHON34\LIB;C:\PYTHON34\LIB\LIB-TK"

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#configuring-python

I have consulted this section (3.3.1. Excursus: Setting environment variables) but to no avail.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a neat trick for installing my applications on Windows. I have spent hours in the past looking at all kinds of fixes that never really worked.

So specifically for Node.js do the following:

1. Download the latest version of Node.js for your machine in my case it was
   node-v0.10.33-x64.msi
2. Create a new folder on your hard drive call it something like, "mydownloads"
   So it looks like this  ------>    c:\mydownloads
3. Move the downloaded file (in step 1) to this new folder.
4. Create a new user on your PC and give that user admin privileges.
5. Log off your PC and log back on as this new user.
6. Open the folder mydownloads then highlight the name of the Node.js file then right click on it then select, "Run As Administrator".
7. Node.js should install.
8. Reboot your machine and log back on using your normal account.

I have found installing MSI packages ( like Node.js ) rarely fail this way.

Jim

Comment: The problem is not installing Node.js, but Noodle.js.